# Python.py file maths in variables

Tags: python

I have a basic salary calculator that should take the input of a user, and then divide the number by certain amounts in order to calculate the users salary in Monthly, Weekly etc. amounts.

If I set the same variables e.g.

```
sal = input("enter:")
mnt = sal / 12
print(mnt)
```

returns

```
{expected amount}
```

However if I have this code in a .py file

```
  sal = input("What's your salary?")
  mnt = sal / 12
  wek = mnt / 4
  day = wek / 5
  hrl = day / 8
  print("""
          Your salary before tax is: 
          Yearly: {}
          Monthly: {}
          Weekly: {}
          Daily: {}
          Hourly: {}
""").format(sal, mnt, wek, day, hrl)
```

I receive the following error after user input.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pysal.py", line 2, in <module>
    mnt = sal / 12
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

## FIX: adding `int` at the start of the input works

**Original answer by @green-cloak-guy**

```
sal = int(input("What's your salary?"))
```

## New Error:

code

```
  1 sal = int(input('What is your salary?'))
  2 mnt = sal / 12
  3 wek = mnt / 4
  4 day = wek / 5
  5 hrl = day / 8
  6 stx = sal * 0.8
  7 mtx = mnt * 0.8
  8 wtx = wek * 0.8
  9 dtx = day * 0.8
 10 htx = hrl * 0.8
 11 print('Your take home before tax is:')
 12 print(f'Yearly: {sal}')
```

Running this code returns this error.

```
  File "pysal.py", line 12
    print(f'Yearly: {sal}')
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why is it invalid syntax? I have tried with both `"` and `'`

Comment: `input()` always returns a string. Try converting it to an integer by doing `int(input("What's your salary?"))` instead.

Comment: What version is your main terminal running

Comment: @Redfer main terminal as in my linux terminal or my Python terminal?

Comment: are you sure the first block of code is returning the expected amount?

Comment: @MacDev yes as sometimes when you run the file your main terminals main python version is set at python 2.7 so you have to set it to the current python file

Comment: @Redfer no I have an alias `py` which is set to `python3`

Comment: @VishalSingh Definitely if I add a `print(sal)` it prints the correct number

Comment: @MacDev i answered it check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sal is type string so change sal to:

```
sal = int(input("Whats your salary"))
```

which would make your main file too:

```
 sal = int(input("What's your salary?"))
 mnt = sal / 12
 wek = mnt / 4
 day = wek / 5
 hrl = day / 8
 print("""
      Your salary before tax is: 
      Yearly: {}
      Monthly: {}
      Weekly: {}
      Daily: {}
      Hourly: {}
 """).format(sal, mnt, wek, day, hrl)
```

Comment: This does work, any idea how I can interpolate the variables in the multi line string? I tried the {varName} way but it just prints with `Yearly: {sal}` instead of  `Yearly: 18000`

Comment: @MacDev you could do you this
 print(f"""
      Your salary before tax is: 
      Yearly: {sal}
      Monthly: {mnt}
      Weekly: {wek}
      Daily: {day}
      Hourly: {hrl}
 """)
If you good with this as an answer i suggest you accept it else it will populate the questions tab

Comment: Hasn't worked unfortunately . Check the bottom of the original post for my current minimal working example

Answer (score 2):

`input()` returns a string. Use `sal = int(input("What's your salary?"))`instead.

Comment: Yes this works! any idea how I can interpolate the variables in the multi line string? I tried the {varName} way but it just prints with Yearly: {sal} instead of Yearly: 18000

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Python 3.6 or newer version to use f-string (`f'Yearly {sal}'`).
Your code works well in Python 3.8 as in the link below.

https://www.pythonpad.co/pads/jknp7beqa3ch1tsy